# How to draw ranges in a plot?

Tags: plotting

I wanna do some plot but I do not know what Mathematica function is best. I wanna draw a 2D plot. Per point in the x Axis I wanna draw ranges, like in the picture I attach [image] You might think about adding error plots, but I do not have central values. These are not errors. I just want the ranges. How is this best implemented?

Comment: `Graphics`, `Line` together with a `List` of coordinates.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
ranges = RandomReal[10, {10, 2}];
ListPlot[Transpose[ranges], 
  Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Directive[Thick, Red]}}, 
  PlotStyle -> None]
```

[image]

> ***if I want the bars to be located at x=1,5,7,12,20,22,30,39,49,51***

To specify horizontal coordinates, you can use

```
ranges = RandomReal[10, {10, 2}];
xvalues = {1, 5, 7, 12, 20, 22, 30, 39, 49, 51};
ListPlot[Transpose[Thread /@ Transpose[{xvalues, ranges}]], 
 Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Directive[Thick, Red]}}, PlotStyle -> None]
```

[image]

You can also do it without the `Filling` option:

```
ListLinePlot[Thread /@ Transpose[{xvalues, ranges}], 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick]]
```

> same picture

Alternatively, you can use `Graphics`:

```
Graphics[{Thick, Red, Line[Thread /@ Transpose[{xvalues, ranges}]]}, 
 Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, AspectRatio -> 1 / GoldenRatio]
```

> same picture

Comment: kglr , I will like to know which version of Methemetica are you using, I Have 11.1.0  and if copy and paste your solution I have not any plot only axes, If I remove PlotStyle -> None I get the lines with dots blue and red on both extremes of lines.

Comment: @AnxonPués, I am using v9. I updated with a variant the works both in version 11.3 and version 9.

Comment: thanks it's ok now, I learn with your solutions

Comment: Thanks! this works. Nonetheless, if I wanna specify the position of the x axis , what is the proper syntax? For instance, In your example, if I want the bars to be located at x=1,5,7,12,20,22,30,39,49,51 ?

Comment: @PhoenixPerson, please see the update

Answer (score 5):

Here is @kglr's idea but different set up.

```
ranges1 = RandomReal[10, 10];
ranges2 = RandomReal[10, 10];
ListPlot[{ranges1, ranges2}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Directive[Thick, Red]}}, PlotStyle -> None]
```

[image]

```
xvalues = {1, 5, 7, 12, 20, 22, 30, 39, 49, 51};
ranges1 = Transpose@{xvalues, RandomReal[10, 10]};
ranges2 = Transpose@{xvalues, RandomReal[10, 10]};
ListPlot[{ranges1, ranges2}, 
 Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, Directive[Thick, Red]}}, PlotStyle -> None]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at `ErrorListPlot` and `ErrorBar`. `ErrorListPlot` takes the same options as `ListPlot` so you can customize is as you want.

load the ErrorBar Plotting Package first

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]

ErrorListPlot[{{2, 0.4}, {1, 0.4}, {3, 0.4}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}]
```

[image]

The same result with the different syntax:

```
ErrorListPlot[{{{1, 2}, ErrorBar[0.4]}, {{2, 1}, 
   ErrorBar[0.4]}, {{3, 3}, ErrorBar[0.4]}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}]
```

[image]

Comment: `ErrorBar` is not needed: `ErrorListPlot[{{1, 2, 0.4}, {2, 1, 0.4}, {3, 3, 0.4}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 4}}]`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, for plots of this type, for readers of the chart that understand statistics, they would prefer you use the `BoxWhiskerChart` command, to embed some of the statistics of the data in the plots.

Here's the example from the manual page for [BoxWhiskerChart](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoxWhiskerChart.html):

```
In[1]:=  data = Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], 1], 100], {\[Mu], {0, 3, 2, 5}}];

In[2]:= BoxWhiskerChart[data]
```

[image]